# How to disable highlight active line in codemirror when editor is not selected?

Tags: codemirror

I only want to have active line on when the current code editor is selected. How would I set this on editor initialisation?

Comment: did you useing the codemirror6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.CodeMirror-focused` class, so that the line is only styled when the cursor is focused within the editor. Then make the normal `.CodeMirror-activeline-background` transparent so that when the cursor is not focused within the editor, it will not be styled.

```
.CodeMirror-activeline-background {
    background: transparent !important;
}
.CodeMirror-focused .CodeMirror-activeline-background {
    background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1) !important;
}
```